# Why some aliases are listed even though they are not set up in config file / .zshrc

Tags: git

When I type:

```
$ git config --get-regexp ^alias
```

I get following list of aliases:

```
alias.unstage reset HEAD --
alias.alias config --get-regexp ^alias\.
alias.logpretty log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
alias.type cat-file -t
alias.dump cat-file -p
alias.aliases config --get-regexp ^alias
```

However in config file there are only last four ones set. Would like to ask where are the first two aliases set/defined, because I have not set them.

Similarly when I type:

```
$ alias
```

There is below list of aliases shown, however within .zshrc, I only did set first two ones:

```
nano='nano ~/.zshrc'
reload='source ~/.zshrc;echo "terminal reloaded"'
run-help=man
which-command=whence
```

Also since there is alias.alias config --get-regexp ^alias. when typing $ alias separately and $ git config --get-regexp ^alias. separately I shall get the same list of aliases. However for first one there is list of aliases from .zshrc while for second one there is list of aliases from config file.

Comment: Try `git config --show-origin --get-regexp ^alias`

Comment: Why are you asking about Git and Zsh in the same question? I don’t see the relation.

Comment: @Guildenstern from lessons my first understanding was that I can set aliases in .zshrc, after I found out that I can set them in config file. How can I clearly distinguish these two, which one to use for what.

Comment: @Guildenstern after running command you stated, I see that those aliases are set in home directory, in file .gitconfig. Is this one so called global one?

Comment: Yes. (11 more to go...)

Comment: You seem to be conflating shell `alias` and git `aliases.  The only thing they have in common is the use of the name `alias`.  They are completely different alias namespaces that apply at different times (shell aliases apply to shell commands, git aliases apply to git commands)